# what should I do about this sqflite problem?

Tags: flutter, sdk, sqflite

name: sqflite
description: A new Flutter project.

The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
pub.dev using `flutter pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev
The following defines the version and build number for your application.
A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
Read more about iOS versioning at https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
sdk: ">=2.17.6 <3.0.0"

Dependencies specify other packages that your package needs in order to work.
To automatically upgrade your package dependencies to the latest versions
consider running `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`. Alternatively,
dependencies can be manually updated by changing the version numbers below to
the latest version available on pub.dev. To see which dependencies have newer
versions available, run `flutter pub outdated`.
dependencies:

flutter:
sdk: flutter
path:
sqflite:

The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

dev_dependencies:
flutter_test:
sdk: flutter

The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
activated in the `analysis_options.yaml` file located at the root of your
package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
rules and activating additional ones.
flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

The following section is specific to Flutter packages.
flutter:

The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
the material Icons class.
uses-material-design: true

To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
assets:
- images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
- images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware

For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
"family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
example:
fonts:
- family: Schyler
fonts:
- asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
- asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
style: italic
- family: Trajan Pro
fonts:
- asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
- asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
weight: 700

For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages

C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat --no-color pub get

Running "flutter pub get" in sqflite...
Error on line 33, column 3 of pubspec.yaml: A package may not list itself as a dependency.

╷
33 │   sqflite:
│   ^^^^^^^
╵
pub get failed (65;    ╵)

Comment: What's your project name in `pubspec.yaml`. Or share your pubspec file

Comment: It's probably an error in indentation, but we can't help you unless you post the full pubspec.yaml in a readable way.

Comment: project name is sqflite